# WordPress select query issue

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to fetch all data from `wp_postmeta` table. I am trying to fetch first `meta_key` column value. so I am running this query.
When I am using `print_r` then all data showing but when I am using foreach loop then its not working.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta" );
foreach($myrows as $value){
    echo $value->sleeps;
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have a post_meta field named `sleeps`? In that case, the value for that field will be in `meta_value`, while the `meta_key` is `sleeps`.

Comment: janh@ yes Any  Idea how to get meta_key value

Comment: Use `$value->meta_value`. But in general, you might want to use `get_post_meta()`, depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: janh@ get_post_meta()  only user post id and i need all mete_key value

Comment: In that case you should be good with using `$value->meta_value`. Does that work, or is something not going as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more for the pot:

`$wpdb->get_col` can be used to return a "single dimensional" array of all values set for "sleeps"

```
global $wpdb;
$values = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'sleeps'" );

echo implode(',', array_unique($values) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well friend this query is solve my issue.

```
global $wpdb;

   $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
                              FROM wp_postmeta 
                              WHERE meta_key = 'sleeps'
                              ORDER BY meta_value");
   if (count($query)) {

  foreach ($query as $state) {
    echo $state->meta_value ;
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta" );
foreach($myrows as $row){
    echo $row->meta_key; // meta key
}
```

Or you can get a post meta keys:

```
$fields = get_post_custom_keys();
foreach ( $fields as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key;
}
```